# Change Access Database password using jet OLEDB in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, password-protection, windows

Can anyone please tell me how I can change the password that I am using to protect my .accdb file, from my windows form application that uses the access file as database source, using OLEDB Connection. I want this to work because I want to grant the user the provition of password changing from default to anything of their choice.
Oledb is preffered but any kind of solution is welcome :) but please donot suggest to open the file in MSAccess & change password. :p
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks steve for your research, I saw those codes but I could not understand how to apply it in my c# form application. However Dai & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264602/how-can-i-create-user-name-and-password-protected-ms-access-2007-file-from-c-sha has freed me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ALTER DATABASE PASSWORD @newPassword @oldPassword` through an `OleDbCommand`.

Comment: Thanks mate for yout help, however it threw Oledb Exception saying can not change password on shared open database but I found help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264602/how-can-i-create-user-name-and-password-protected-ms-access-2007-file-from-c-sha